# using data-rel tag, link to a div in dinamically process with Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to do a Facybox, using this method in the tutorial : http://sohtanaka.developpez.com/tutoriels/javascript/creez-fenetre-modale-avec-css-et-jquery/fichiers/

The problem is that the "data-rel" tag seems to don't work in dinamically circumstances. here is my code:

```html
  <div class="row prod">
    <% @type1.each do |product| %>
      <div class="product-tile">
        <div class="entry col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col">
          <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
          <div class="product_img img-responsive">
            <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
            <a href="#" data-width="1000" data-rel="popup1" class="poplight discover">Discover</a>
             <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
              <div id="popup1" class="popup_block">
                <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
                 <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
                 <p>Soh Tanaka est traduit sur developpez.com.</p>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="product_description">
            <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
            <div class="price_line">
              <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <%end%>
  </div>
```

The <%=product.title%> and <%product.image_url%> gives me always the same result : the first occurrence from my database. how could I fix it?
Thanks!

edit : 
my @type1 is just checking the occurence in the "product_line" as you can see:

```html
StoreController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @products = Product.order(:title)
    @type1 = @products.where(:product_line =>"1")
    @type2 = @products.where(:product_line =>"2")
  end
end
```

Comment: To help us understand what is going on you'll want to also show us what you are setting `@type1` to in your controller.

Comment: I do not understand why it is important, but I edited it if it can help you.

Comment: How many products are contained in `@type1` after you set it?  And if it is just one, is that one by any chance the one that it is showing the `image_url` and `title` for?  ie the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reuse HTML IDs, so you will have to make sure each popup has a unique id.  Try using an index and adding it to the popup's id:

```
<div class="row prod">
  <% @type1.each_with_index do |product, index| %>
    <div class="product-tile">
      <div class="entry col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-0 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0 col col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-0 col">
        <h3><%= product.title %></h3>
        <div class="product_img img-responsive">
          <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
          <a href="#" data-width="1000" data-rel="popup<%= index %>" class="poplight discover">Discover</a>
           <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
            <div id="popup<%= index %>" class="popup_block">
               <h3><%=product.title%></h3>
               <%= image_tag(product.image_url, :class => 'the_img') %>
                <p>Soh Tanaka est traduit sur developpez.com.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product_description">
          <%= sanitize(product.description)%>
          <div class="price_line">
            <span class="price"><%=number_to_currency(product.price)%></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
</div>
```

Comment: My products are of two types : 1 and 2, for the two products lines. When I display my products in my view, it works well, they are well classed by types. The issue is when I try to display the informations linked to my products, especiallly in the div, linked with "data-rel" tag. It seems that my problem really comes from this "data rel" tag

Comment: I see what you're saying. I'm sorry I misunderstood. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: also, as a bonus, you could use link_to:

`<%= link_to 'Discover', '#', class: %w(poplight discover), data: { rel: "popup#{index}", width: "1000"} %>`

Comment: Thanks It works well! But I didn't really understood how It works, so I don't know how to fix what happens : My type2 products are displaying my type1 products when I click

Comment: In each loop, maybe add some other piece of info to the id, like "popup_type1_<%=index%>” and "popup_type2_<%=index%>”

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me a lot!!

Comment: If my answer helped you, I would really appreciate it if you could mark it as accepted.  I am answering questions to try to gain more points. If you don't mark answers as accepted it doesn't encourage people like me to help people like you.

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: You should be able to hit the green check mark and mark it as correct.

Comment: no problem!  I'm very glad to help.  Sorry if I came off as pushy about accepting it.  It's frustrating when I help someone and they don't accept the answer after saying it was what helped. :)